# How do I get a value from a specific column in a vb.net datagridview?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have created a datatable as the source for my datagridview as follows:

```
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Clear()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    dt.Columns.Add("Customer")
    dt.Columns.Add("Dtime")
    dt.Columns.Add("Title")
    dt.Columns.Add("EventID")
```

The EventID is numeric and will be passed to a new form to tell it which record to open (that bit works I use it on another form).

I have tried:

```
event = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Value.ToString
event = Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(3).Value.ToString)
event = Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1.Item("EventID", DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString)
```

and probably a dozen other ways I've found on this site and others but I keep getting the same error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
```

It's driving me insane, what am I doing wrong? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
event = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Value.ToString()
```